# Using grep to search for file containing some text

Tags: linux, grep, debian

I am using the following command to find the file containing the text "Your server is now running"

```
grep -rnw '/' -e "Your server is now running"
```

However the command returns

```
grep: /proc/sysrq-trigger: Input/output error
```

What am I doing wrong with the command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are searching through special files in `/proc`, `/sys` and `/dev`.

Some of them are not readable like normal files. At best, you get a simple error like this. In other cases, the search will hang forever reading garbage data (`grep foo /dev/zero` for example).

Limit your search to where data files are usually found, such as `/var`, `/usr`, `/etc` and `/home`.

PS: The search could take hours. If you're trying to find a Glassfish installation, this is not the way to go.